# Link to be unavailable at specific time everyday

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var now = new Date();
    var millisTill10 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 10, 0, 0, 0) - now;
    if (millisTill10 < 0) {
         millisTill10 += 86400000; // it's after 10am, try 10am tomorrow.
    }
    setTimeout(function(){alert("It's 10am!")}, millisTill10);
</script>
```

I'd like to create a JavaScript/jQuery to make a link unavailable at a specific time of the day.

Basically, I have a chat with us link that I want to add a class `available` every working day (Mon-Fri) at 9am, and addClass `unavailable` at 5pm (SERVER TIME if possible).

```
<div id="chatLink">
<a class="" href="/app/chat">Chat with us</a>
</div>
```

I tried using the `Date.now()` but it only works once for that day and cannot repeat everyday. Am I missing something? Is there anyway to have it run every working day?

UPDATE: I found another code snippet on SOF, but that doesn't actually work. This is my first time using the Date function

Comment: `Date.now()` returns the user's time set. Which would vary with different users. You need to get the current time from the server and then act on that.

Comment: The JS/jQuery code you have already written would help. Consider creating a JSFiddle for this. I would also note that this seems like something better implemented on the server side, rather than client side, if that is an option.

Comment: Do you mean 9-5 in the user's timezone, or yours?

Comment: @shadow Great point!! I want it to be server time if possible.

Comment: @MichaelEvans I added it thanks!

Comment: @AminJafari Can I use JS to pull server time?

Comment: of course, you need to make a request to the server, then return the time from the server to the client and use the response.

Comment: Use AJAX with PHP's [getdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php) .

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick. Please note that blue background means `visible` and red means `invisible`. Change the styling accordingly to show or hide the element. It's only for example purposes.

```js
var link = document.querySelector('#link')

function updateLink() {
  // This will initialize date with
  // the local time of the visiting user
  var date = new Date()
  // You can also init the date with your server time
  // var date = new Date('Aug 24 2017 19:00:00 EST')
  // var date = new Date('Aug 24 2017 19:00:00 GMT-0500')
  var hour = date.getHours()
  var day = date.getDay()
  if (hour >= 9 && hour < 17 && day >= 1 && day < 6) {
    link.classList.remove('invisible')
    link.classList.add('visible')
  } else {
    link.classList.remove('visible')
    link.classList.add('invisible')
  }
}

updateLink()
setInterval(updateLink, 30000)
```

```css
#link {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
}

#link.visible {
  background: blue;
}

#link.invisible {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatLink">
  <a id="link" href="/app/chat">Chat with us</a>
</div>
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, this will act on the visiting user's timezone. That could be a problem for someone on the other side of the world who would get barred pretty much at the opposite time intended... The OP hasn't specified whether or not this is desired behaviour though.

Comment: @shadow you're totally correct. But that wasn't included in the author's question :) That's only the base he can work on and correct the code with his timezone.

Comment: @jimmyweb Thanks for the answer! Is there anyway I can use the server time with this code?

Comment: Sure. You need to get it in proper format and initialize `date` variable in `updateLink` function with proper timezone. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MZ Please accept the answer if you find it helpful :) Thanks

Comment: @jimmyweb how can I pull the current server time? Can you add the code to the snippet?

Comment: @jimmyweb or at least set a timezone

Comment: You need to have server API to do that ;) But this is out of scope of your question.